# Transpose data from multiple rows per person to one row per person in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, reshape, spread

I've got data set showing each persons' candy preferences. Each person has multiple rows to display all of the candy that they like, like shown below.

```
Name      ID      Candy
Alex      101     Kit Kat
Alex      101     Twix
Sam       102     Reeses
Charlie   103     Skittles
Charlie   103     Twix
Charlie   103     Kit Kat
Charlie   103     Hershey
Nia       104     M&M
Nia       104     Skittles
Nia       104     Reeses
...
```

I want to convert this to a person-level data set where the Candy columns are limited to the first 3 listed.

```
Name      ID     Candy 1    Candy 2    Candy 3
Alex      101    Kit Kat    Twix       NA
Sam       102    Reeses     NA         NA
Charlie   103    Skittles   Twix       Kit Kat
Nia       104    M&M        Skittles   Reeses
```

I originally tried to use the Spread function, but I believe it doesn't work because the number of rows per person is variable.

Is there a way to achieve this in R? I'm not quite sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: Group the data, take the first 3 rows per group, add a column that counts rows within groups, and then reshape

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `summarise()` the data by ID and Name, use `toString()` to collapse the candy variable then separate it into individual columns:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID, Name) %>%
  summarise(Candy = toString(Candy)) %>%
  separate(Candy, into = paste0("Candy", 1:3), sep = ", ", fill = "right", extra = "drop")

# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   ID [4]
     ID Name    Candy1   Candy2   Candy3 
  <int> <chr>   <chr>    <chr>    <chr>  
1   101 Alex    Kit Kat  Twix     NA     
2   102 Sam     Reeses   NA       NA     
3   103 Charlie Skittles Twix     Kit Kat
4   104 Nia     M&M      Skittles Reeses
```